# Vector Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection, map-projections

I am watching a youtube video on Principal Component Analysis. It is written that the projection of vector $x_i$ onto vector $u_1$ is

$proj_{u_{1}}(x_i) = {u_1}^T  x_i u$

where $u$ is the unit vector of $u_1$

This is slightly different from the normal projection equation.

$proj_{u_{1}}(x_i) =  \frac{x_i  u_1}{|| u_1|| } . u $

It seemed that the only different is ${u_1}^T$ and $\frac{u_1}{|| u_1|| }$. How is ${u_1}^T$ equivalent to $\frac{u_1}{|| u_1|| }$? Please advise thanks.

[Youtube link at 4:51 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhK8nbtii6I&t=308s)

I tried with both equation but can't get some answer. Please help

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([[1,3]])
u1 = np.array([[2,2]])

u = np.array([[2,2]]) / np.sqrt(8)

#equation 1
proj1 = u1.transpose()*x1*u
>array([[ 1.41421356,  4.24264069],
       [ 1.41421356,  4.24264069]])

#equation 2
proj2 = x1*u*u
>array([[ 0.5,  1.5]])
```

Comment: Note that $proj_v(u)=\frac{u v^T}{\|v\|}v$. Since $uv^T$ is scalar as $u,v$ are row vectors and matrix multiplication is associative we have $uv^T=v^Tu$.Substitute in the original you will get what you want.

Comment: @Tutankhamun Associative, but not commutative. $uv^\top$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin True multiplication is not commutative $uv^T$ is scalar as u and v are $1\times n$ matrices which is simply vector dot product.

Comment: I write vectors as columns, not rows. Then your other product is a square matrix..

Comment: He did say it would be easier to understand if you watched his previous videos. Apparently he always assumes the vector you project onto is a unit vector. Explained here: https://youtu.be/X78tLBY3BMk?t=267

Comment: @David K, can you please explain the steps by steps? I try with some dummy vector $x_i = <1,3>, u_i = <2, 2>$ but I cant get the same results.

Comment: $\langle 2,2\rangle$ is not a unit vector. Try $\langle \sqrt2/2, \sqrt2/2\rangle$ instead. By the way, I don't agree with the way this instructor expects you to remember this assumption. It would take little effort to include the correction factor for the magnitude of the vector, and even less effort to simply say "unit vector" each time he uses a unit vector to represent the direction of a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the begining of this video, the presenter says that as a prerequisite for this video you should watch his video on vector projections.  Did you watch is video on vector projections?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X78tLBY3BMk

The "normal" definition of projection as it is taught in a pre-calculus class is:

$proj_{u}(v) =  \frac{u\cdot v}{|| u||^2 }  u$

Where "$\cdot$" is the "dot" product (Euclidean inner product).  The first factor is a scalar; the second factor is a vector.  Together we have a vector that represents the component of $v$ in the direction of $u.$

Note that this is quite a bit different from what you have written as "normal."

Anyway, how do you get from $proj_{u}(v) =  \frac{u\cdot v}{|| u||^2 }  u$ to $proj_{u}(v) =  u^Tv u$?

First, $u,v$ are column vectors.  This means that $u^Tv = u\cdot v.$
Second, $u$ is defined in this video to be a unit vector, so $\|u\|= 1$ and can be ignored.

Comment: Hi Thanks! Yes I watched the previous video shown in your link. So, in the PCA Video, it is written, $proj_{u_{1}}(x_i) = {u_1}^T  x_i u$ but he only mentioned the $u$ being the unit vector, but the $u_1$ is not a unit vector. So why $||u_{1}|| ? = 1$?

Comment: @josephgan He may be missing a subscript on the second $u_1.$ I've never seen anyone turn a vector into a unit vector by removing the subscript. Usually if you start with a non-unit vector and want to write a unit vector in the same direction you put a hat on the name of the vector, whereas removing the subscript would give you a different vector, usually in a different direction, which makes no sense for projection.